# How can I create an mp3 file using C++?

Tags: c++, mp3

So, I have two audio files with short audio labels, as well as two vectors in which the time points in which I need to insert these audio labels are recorded. How can I create an mp3 file in C++ so that these labels from the file are inserted into it at times from the vector? Eventually I will need to save this mp3 file.

Comment: What did you already achieve? What blocks you? Which libraries are you using for the (simpler) steps? E.g. generate any mp3 from c++? Copying from one mp3 to a new one, on audio level instead of file level? Editing mp3 in any similar simpler way? I mean are you only asking about how to do those things based on the time vector, or is any of those steps in itself already a problem for you?

Comment: @Yunnosch The fact is that I do not know how to implement this in principle, so I have only the initial data and no ideas yet. I know that this is wrong, but I still hope that they will be able to tell me the right direction of the idea.

Comment: The right direction of the idea is: Find a library advertising to do mp3 file manipulation. Read the manual, try a tutorial.  Your question as is lacks focus on a specific problem you encountered while trying that.

Comment: @VladimirBait MP3 doesn't support this directly.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the MP3 container format does not support that, only [audio chunks](http://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/frame_header.html) that are wavelet transform-encoded and what is known as [ID3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) metadata to have information like artist, track name, encoding quality genre etc..

One possible solution may be [(web-)RTC](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/datachannels/) which supports multiple channels some of which may have audio, but possibly also other types of data can be streamed, such as your timing data.

Comment: You're right about the MP3 stream format, but WebRTC isn't relevant here.

Comment: I guess there isn't enough reason to suggest a multi-channel web-based streaming protocol as a possible solution. 2 audio containers that support multiple *audio* streams are m4a/mp4 and wma/asf, but that would require the data to be resilient to the codec which may be lossy, so also not really an option.